# Can´t find Jquery script to sort/change <div> structure, Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webshop

I have a webshop. 
There is a company that provides me it. 
So they stay for the host and database.
I have a admin side to could manage the webshop. There I can change the CSS, HTML, and JavaScripts of the website with some exeptions.

I want to change one of this exeptions "the checkout page structure", the support from the company that provides my webshop says that I have to change the structure with JavaScript.
Am a user friendly of Jquery.

Theory:
(This is how it looks like now on the end-client side):

```
**Products list on the cart:**
------------------------------
I   Art1   10$   10units     I
I   Art2    5$    4units     I
I   Art3    1$    1units     I
------------------------------

**Payments method:**
--------------
I   Visa     I
I   Invoice  I
I   SMS      I
--------------

**Freight Alternative:**
-------------------
I   Ordinarie     I
I   DHL Saver     I
I   DHL Express   I
-------------------

**Adress Alternative:**
-----------------------
I   Actually adress   I
I   Customer Name     I
I   Customer Telefon  I
-----------------------
```

(This is how I want it to look like on the end-client side):

```
**Products list on the cart: Payments method: Freight Alternative: Adress Alternative:**
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I   Art1   10$   10units     I   Visa     I   Ordinarie     I   Actually adress   I
I   Art2    5$    4units     I   Invoice  I   DHL Saver     I   Customer Name     I
I   Art3    1$    1units     I   SMS      I   DHL Express   I   Customer Telefon  I
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In general terms, this is how it looks like the Default HTML Checkout page the company offer me.

```
<html><!-- CHECKOUT PAGE DEFAULT STRUCTURE -->
<body>

<div>List products on the cart, Example: Art1, Art2, Art3, prices, quantities</div>
<div>
  <div>Payment method, Example: Visa, Invoice, SMS</div>
  <div>Freight method, Example: ordinary, UPS saver, UPS express</div>
  <div>Customer address, Example: Delivery adress, Phone number, Contact person</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Step 1: Find some JQuery alternative script, to could change the structure.

```
    <html><!-- CHECKOUT PAGE DEFAULT STRUCTURE -->


<!-- MAGICAL JQUERY SCRIPT FROM STACKOVERFLOW ANSWER -->
<script>
script
script
</script>
<!-- END -->


    <body>

    <div>List products on the cart, Example: Art1, Art2, Art3, prices, quantities</div>
    <div>
      <div>Payment method, Example: Visa, Invoice, SMS</div>
      <div>Freight method, Example: ordinary, UPS saver, UPS express</div>
      <div>Customer address, Example: Delivery adress, Phone number, Contact person</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Step 2: Configure the Jquery script to break the  structures from the default page.
So when I refresh the page after saving the new script it looks like this.

```
        <html><!-- CHECKOUT PAGE DEFAULT STRUCTURE -->


    <!-- MAGICAL JQUERY SCRIPT FROM STACKOVERFLOW ANSWER -->
    <script>
    script
    script
    </script>
    <!-- END -->


        <body>
          <table>
           <tr>

<td>          <div>List products on the cart, Example: Art1, Art2, Art3, prices, quantities</div></td>
<td>          <div>Payment method, Example: Visa, Invoice, SMS</div></td>
<td>          <div>Freight method, Example: ordinary, UPS saver, UPS express</div></td>
<td>          <div>Customer address, Example: Delivery adress, Phone number, Contact person</div></td>

          </tr>
          </table>        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Any ideas?
I have find some Jquery Sorting structure. But didn´t look so fresh, and simple. I am missing some new, simple stuff? or Should I use the uggly variants?

Regards from Sweden.
Please let me know if Is not easy to understand the question!

Comment: Structural changes are not a task for JS/jQuery. Either just change the CSS of the page to get a different layout, or modify the code that generates the html markup (yet you should not use tables for layout)

Comment: it has nothing to do with jQuery or javaScript! you need to restructure your html

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `float:left` to all the main div's.